# Can I export my xcode project game to Unity?

Tags: ios, iphone, unity-game-engine

I need your help where I want to export my game that is exported from Unity 3d now after making some changes in the xcode project, I want to export it again as Unity package that can be opened in Unity SDK.

Help and suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Comment: What kind of changes did you make? There is no "export" from Xcode to unity but there are some workarounds that can help you.

Comment: Please share those workarounds.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you added some files to Xcode project than the simplest way will be to use [Post Process pipeline](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/BuildPlayerPipeline.html). You can modify Xcode project with help of [mod-pbxproj](https://github.com/kronenthaler/mod-pbxproj) script. It is written in Python (yep, one more language to learn :). But it is quite simple and straightforward.

If you modified some Unity-generated Objective-C files then you are in trouble because no one can guarantee that Unity guys will not make some changes that will ruin your code. So you should be very careful there. But you still can automate this exciting process by using Makefiles. The main thing Unity does is generates Data and Library folders for Xcode. So you can create Xcode project, store it somewhere near Unity files and then write Makefile or some script that will do the following:

1. Export Unity project to Xcode by using Unity batch mode (you'll need Pro license to do it)
2. Copy Data and Library folders from exported project to your target project
3. Delete exported project

This all is not fun at all but it can solve your problems.

Comment: Actually, I want to modify some gameObjects as well as some scenes but unfortunately I don't have the actual unity packages of the game so can I able to access those by the xcode project exporting it to Unity ? Please guide

Comment: Unfortunately you cannot. When Unity exports project to Xcode it converts all resources to some internal format for runtime loading.  And Unity cannot read this format by itself.